# Placing widgets in matplotlib: understanding how axes work

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created a `matplotlib` plot with some buttons, which can vary the plot parameters and therefore update the plot. It works perfectly, but I have not been able to understand the logic of placing the buttons (or any other matplotlib widgets).

For example, in the [matplotlib official button example](http://matplotlib.org/1.5.1/examples/widgets/buttons.html), it places the widgets by calling `plt.axes()`, and then passing the ax element to the Button constructor:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

freqs = np.arange(2, 20, 3)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.001)
s = np.sin(2*np.pi*freqs[0]*t)
l, = plt.plot(t, s, lw=2)


class Index(object):
    ind = 0

    def next(self, event):
        self.ind += 1
        i = self.ind % len(freqs)
        ydata = np.sin(2*np.pi*freqs[i]*t)
        l.set_ydata(ydata)
        plt.draw()

    def prev(self, event):
        self.ind -= 1
        i = self.ind % len(freqs)
        ydata = np.sin(2*np.pi*freqs[i]*t)
        l.set_ydata(ydata)
        plt.draw()

callback = Index()
axprev = plt.axes([0.7, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
axnext = plt.axes([0.81, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
bnext = Button(axnext, 'Next')
bnext.on_clicked(callback.next)
bprev = Button(axprev, 'Previous')
bprev.on_clicked(callback.prev)

plt.show()
```

As explained in `matplotlib`'s documentation, `axes` method gets a list as input with the elements `[xmin xmax ymin ymax]`.

Since the `Axes` element is (please correct if wrong) just the area where the axis and the plot appear, setting `[xmin xmax ymin ymax]` is not an understandable way of placing things correctly.

I don't know if the problem is that the example is too simple and there is another more adequate way of placing things all over the `Figure`, or if I am not understanding how to place (**and scale!**) elements correctly.

Any help?

Comment: I think that it's `plt.axes((left, bottom, width, height))`. Does that work?